# How to offset random sine angles as a whole?

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra, trigonometry

I have randomly generated sin values using angles:

```
sin(12)
sin(33)
sin(75)
sin(125)
...
```

I want to add a fixed rotation to all of these and wondering if there is an elegant way to do this? I was thinking of doing some comparisons and checks to see if the angle + my_additional_angle is negative and greater than certain values so as to add my fixed angle appropriately but wanted to ask for a simpler way first.

Also this has to be solved within these constraints, i.e. I can't use matrices, etc, because the application that defines these is very limited.

Lastly the random angle is between 0 and 180. The angle I am adding can be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, trig functions work in radians, not degrees, so you almost certainly want:

```
sin(radians(12))
sin(radians(33))
# etc
```

To add an angle, if you do so before you take the `sin` it's really easy, just

```
sin(radians(12+angle))
sin(radians(33+angle))
```

It should not matter if the angle if negative or greater than 360, `sin` will still work correctly, so that `sin(radians(12)) == sin(radians(12+360)) == sin(radians(12-360))`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention, this application when they implemented their scripting API, they added new functions like their own sin/cos that takes degrees. This is not very important but I did what you explained in degrees, but when I am increasing the angle value I add, I see that some values rotate faster than others, so not sure if this is wrong or there is another issue.

Comment: You would expect that if you add an constant angle, the `sin` increases at different rates depending on the initial angle.  For example, for small additional angles, at 90 deg, `sin` will change very slowly, and at 0 deg, sin will change quickly.  (Generally changing quickest when the value is close to 0 and fastest when close to 1 or -1.)

Comment: It also sounds like it might be worth doing a few checks to make sure that you are using this right. For example, sin(A+90)=cos(A), sin(A+180)=-sin(A), etc.

Comment: Oh so do you know any way to ensure uniform changes for all values? I thought it would be possible. When I have values that are equally spaced apart then it works, i.e. for angles such as 10, 20, 30, 40, etc. Just not when they are random. Yes those equations you wrote show up correct.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean by "uniform changes for all values"?  Do you mean you want `sin(A)-sin(A+C)==sin(B)-sin(B+C)`, that is `A` and `B` are two different starting angles, `C` is the change in angle for both of these, and the subtraction give the change in the result??  (If this is what you want, then `sin` won't work in general.)

Comment: Basically I want the random points generated by sin to appear rotated as a whole with the addition of my angle. So adding 30 degrees should rotate all the values as a whole.

Comment: Actually I found the bug, it was inside seed generated. Now it works. Thanks.